# Code converted from Java to Kotlin - not working

Tags: java, kotlin

The code below was converted from Java and some of it did not convert over. I'm trying to get this all converted to Kotlin.

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PersonViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.mImage.setImageResource(mPersonList[position].personImage)
        holder.mTitle.text = mPersonList[position].personName
        holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener {

//Unresolved reference:Java
            val intent = intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
//Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted(!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type intent?               
intent.putExtra("Title", mPersonList[holder.adapterPosition].personName)
                intent.putExtra("Description", mPersonList[holder.adapterPosition].personDescription)
                intent.putExtra("Image", mPersonList[holder.adapterPosition].personImage)
                mContext.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener {
     val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)              
     intent.putExtra("Title", mPersonList[holder.adapterPosition].personName)
     intent.putExtra("Description", mPersonList[holder.adapterPosition].personDescription)
     intent.putExtra("Image", mPersonList[holder.adapterPosition].personImage)
     mContext?.startActivity(intent)
        }
```